# the best way to navigation previous/next article on a website

Tags: jquery, html

On a website I intend to have a list of articles

//main page

```
<body>
<a href="/article1_name.html">article1 title</a> 
<a href="/article2_some_other_name.html/">article2 title</a> 
<a href="/article3_another_name.html/">article3 title</a> 
...
<a href="/article10_yet_another_name.html/">article10 title</a> 
</body>
```

Once click into article1 title and redirect to article1 page, I am hoping to implement a previous/next page navigation like this in each of the article page:
[image]

However I do not wish to hardcode the previous and next hyperlink on every page. What is the best way to do this? I am not sure the right term to search for such a problem. Pagination seems to refer to something else (how many article to show on the main page), whereas my issue concerns how to identify previous and next page dynamically in a list of articles. Thanks.

Comment: Store the articles on the server, and have the server automatically insert the proper link for you using whichever back-end language. You can also uniquely identify articles by IDs, and link to, eg, `/article/123`, and your server can reply with the right article

Comment: I'm sure that works but I'm even less familiar with how to have the server auto insert a link. Is there any front-end solution for beginners?

Comment: An elegant general solution for this *will* require a backend. (of course, you can continue hard-coding, if you like...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also try this approach.

Requires adding class="currentArticle" to the current article being viewed.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>    

            function prevPage(){
                var currentArticle = document.getElementsByClassName("currentArticle");
                currentArticle[0].previousElementSibling.click();
            }

            function nextPage(){
                var currentArticle = document.getElementsByClassName("currentArticle");
                currentArticle[0].nextElementSibling.click();
            }           

        </script>
    </head>

<body>  
      <div onClick="prevPage()">arrow left image placeholder</div>
      <a href="/article1_name.html" >article1 title</a> 
      <a href="/article2_some_other_name.html/" class="currentArticle">article2 title</a> 
      <a href="/article3_another_name.html/">article3 title</a> 
      ...
      <a href="/article10_yet_another_name.html/">article10 title</a> 
      <div onClick="nextPage()">arrow right image placeholder</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Technically you could do it like this:

```
var parts = window.location.href.split('/'); //Splits the url by /
var articleString = parts[parts.length - 1].split('_')[0]; //Finds last / and first string before the _
var matches = articleString.match(/\d+$/); //Gets the string form of the number
var currentArticleNum = parseInt(matches[0]); //Parses the number.
```

However, this is really hacky and as burriko said, you should do this serverside.